# Comment se moquer des Anglais ?

Tags: histoire, insultes

J'ai récemment commencé à jouer un jeu de table (*A Few Acres of Snow*) qui traite de la guerre entre les Anglais et les Français dans la Nouvelle France du 18ème siècle.

Je sais comment insulter des gens, mais dans le cadre du jeu, j'aimerais savoir me moquer de l'autre joueur d'une façon appropriée. Existe-il des insultes qui s'adressent spécifiquement aux Anglais, et qui (idéalement) étaient courantes au 18ème siècle ?

PS: Les anglophones ont du mal a se moquer des Français, [apparemment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44062/how-to-mock-the-french).

Comment: Il y a 11 siècles d'écart, mais je pense que dans le contexte de ce jeu tu peux utiliser « knight » prononcé à la française (donc phonétiquement : \[knigt\]) ou encore toutes celles que l'on peut écouter ici : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9V7zbWNznbs :)

Comment: Une fille de ma connaisance disait, quand arrivaient ses règles, "Voilà les anglais qui débarquent"!

Comment: « tête carrée » utilisé par les francophones du Canada pour [désigner les Canadiens de langue anglaise](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/articles/avoir-la-tete-enflee-et-autres-expressions-quebecoises-avec-tete/). La [BDLP](https://www.bdlp.org/) ne l'associe [aux anglophones à compter de la seconde moitié du XXe s](https://www.bdlp.org/resultat?base=QU&query=517162,0), je trouve cet article un peu confus sur la datation mais dans le contexte de [*A few acres of snow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Few_Acres_of_Snow) le terme semble plus adaptée que d'autres proposés dans les réponses.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Traditionnellement on traite les Anglais de [*rosbifs*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rosbif), qui date apparemment au moins du dix-neuvième.
- Pour des anglais riches ou nobles, [*milord*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Milord), attesté également eu moins depuis le dix-neuvième. [Et plus récemment](http://youtu.be/d00o1_zUync)...
- [Angliche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/Angliche)
- D'après le wiktionnaire [*tête carrée*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/t%C3%AAte_carr%C3%A9e), [*godon*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/Godon), [*brit*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/Brit) et plus récemment [*bloke*](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wiktionary/fr/wiki/bloke)

Globalement *cochon* peut s'ajouter un peu partout « Cochons d'Anglais ! ».

Comment: Dans _[Surcouf](http://www.bedetheque.com/serie-1044-BD-Surcouf.html)_, le plus utilisé est _goton_ (plutôt que _godon_, mais il y a aussi _goddam_). _Rosbif_ y est aussi courant, ainsi que le complet _mangeur de rosbif_ que je trouve plus amusant.

Comment: As-tu des références sur l'utilisation péjorative de _milord_ ? Je ne l'ai jamais pris comme tel.  ([Piaf](http://www.frmusique.ru/texts/p/piaf_edith/milord.htm))

Comment: @Unrancophone: Pas vraiment péjoratif, mais moqueur « Et bien Milord, on est dans l'embarras ? ». Mais non, je n'ai pas de sources.

Comment: Ce n'est pas le mot qui est ironique, c'est le contexte. Toute formule respectueuse employée dans un contexte ou le respect est visiblement absent va fournir une charge d'ironie supplémentaire.

Comment: @Unrancophone: Juste. C'est quand même un bon appellatif à mon sens.

Comment: @Evpok: "Eh bien Milord, on est dans l'embarras" - oui, je vais utiliser ça. :)

Comment: Tu peux aussi lui balancer un « Alors, toujours sûr que "God save zeu king" ? » bien placé.

Comment: Difficile aussi de ne pas penser, malgré la différence d'époque par rapport au 18e siècle, à la très fameuse tirade du *french taunt* dans « Sacré Graal » des Monty Python. Une référence loufoque si cela peut t'inspirer...

Comment: Les angliches 

Answer (score 4):

Je rajouterai bien *bouffeurs de gelée à la menthe* comme moquerie sympathique ; l'inconvénient c'est que l'on s'expose à être traité de *mangeur de cuisses de grenouille* en retour !

Answer (score 3):

Je ne connais que le traditionnel "Rosbeef"
Mais pour parler de l'Angleterre, il y a bien sûr, la "perfide Albion".
Et "les anglois" n'est pas forcément péjoratif, mais fait "vieux français".

Comment: Voire *l'anglois*, qui fera encore plus couleur temporellement locale.

Comment: Selon Wikipédia, "perfide Albion" a été utilisé par Bossuet dès le XVIIe siècle.

Answer (score 1):

Une façon moqueuse de qualifier les Anglais, particulièrement chez les marins, est ***glaouch***.

Ce mot vient du breton où il signifie à l'origine "[rustre](http://www.devri.bzh/recherche/?q=glaouch)", "[maladroit](https://fr.glosbe.com/br/fr/glaouch)", "[mou, molasson](https://audierne.info/les-bretonnismes-quel-glaouch/)", "[un peu bête, gland](https://dico-des-mots.com/definitions/glaouch.html)".

Voici un exemple d'utilisation :

> Les "Glaouches" viennent défier les "Frogs" sur leur terrain.

[Le Monde, 7 novembre 2008](https://www.lemonde.fr/sport/article/2008/11/07/les-glaouches-viennent-defier-les-frogs-sur-leur-terrain_1116103_3242.html).

Answer (score 0):

One may pick some ideas from the famous French Taunter. A character from the celebrated comedy "Monty Python and the Holy Grail". Especially if the English or and French interlocutors are familiar with the film and the character. See

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DGXx56WqqJw

https://montypython.fandom.com/wiki/French_Taunter

http://www.montypython.net/scripts/HG-tauntscene1.php

(I am aware of course that the film refers to another period than the 18th century.)