# Que signifie "beefsteaks" ici ?

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Dans *Le pont de Londres* :

> Il travaillait pour une maison? pour Seflridge? Pour Harrow
> Brothers?... ils voulaient savoir! et puis ce style! ce battant! qu'il
> avait foutu la pagaille dans la cohue des gros du [Scotland] Yard! les
> **beefsteaks** de choc!

Savez-vous ce que signifie le mot "beefsteaks" ici ? Selon le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/beefsteak/8608), *beefsteak* est la forme anglaise de *bifteck*, mais je ne comprends pas très bien le sens de ce mot ici.

Comment: *Beefsteaks* ou *Rosebeef* (roastbeef) sont deux façons d'appeler les Anglais de la “perfide Albion”, cela tient à leur façon de cuire la viande rouge.

Comment: Céline appuie sur toutes sortes de pitons dans son oeuvre qui déclenche des trucs même outre-atlantique pcq. chez moi _les boeufs_, (prononcé ..eux) c'est un terme qui désigne les policiers !

Comment: On ne sait même pas pourquoi ces termes qui font référence à la viande rouge sont utilisés (Plat préféré ? Couleur de l'habillement  ? Couleur de la peau après un coup de soleil ? Ce sont toujours, en tout cas, des choix gratuits, sans racine d'un mépris réel, des choix d'enfants). Voir [L'autre - étymologie des insultes](http://projetbabel.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=102)

Comment: @LPH … si, on sait pourquoi : faire cuire un morceau de bœuf “à la ficelle”, c'est tremper une pièce de bœuf dans de l'eau bouillante en la laissant ‘crue’ à cœur … méthode inconnue de ce côté de la Manche.— [Ne vous fiez pas au site non sécurisé auquel votre lien fait référence, et n'en déduisez pas des jugements incompatibles avec l'esprit de ce site s.v.p.]

Comment: @Personne  Comment font-ils leur compte ces individus qui prétendent justifier que pour les anglais un bouilli c'est du rôti ? Dans votre anglais faut-il dire « roast » pour « bouilli » ?

Comment: _rosbif_: **cuisson**. « Sortir le rosbif du réfrigérateur au moins une heure avant la cuisson. Le mettre au four préchauffé à 220-240 °C, pour saisir l'extérieur, puis abaisser la température vers 200 °C et cuire de 10 à 15 min par livre selon l'épaisseur de la pièce. Le laisser reposer 5 min dans le four éteint, porte ouverte, puis le sortir et attendre encore quelques minutes : les sucs se répartiront mieux dans la chair uniformément rose et chaude à cœur, qui sera plus facile à découper. Mettre sur le feu la lèchefrite. Colorer légèrement les sucs, dégraisser en partie, puis déglacer... »

Comment: « ...avec un peu de fond de veau brun clair ou d'eau. Mouiller avec le double du volume de jus à obtenir ; faire réduire de moitié. Vérifier l'assaisonnement ; ajouter éventuellement un peu de caramel à sauce pour rectifier la couleur. Passer au chinois et servir en saucière, à part. » (_Le Grand Larousse gastronomique_, éd. 2007, à « rosbif »).

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/comment-se-moquer-des-anglais

Comment: @LPH … « … ces individus qui prétendent justifier que pour les *anglais* … » … *Anglais* … décidément, du haut de vos certitudes livresques, la francophonie vous est inaccessible ! Je laisse au modérateur le soin de vous faire entendre que cette phrase ressemble à une insulte lorsqu'on se réfère aux commentaires précédents …  — https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131008/discussion-between-lph-and-none

Comment: @Personne Un beau cercle (vicieux)… de liens … de rosbif !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je pense qu'il s'agit ici d'une qualification (péjorative) des Anglais. L'injure habituelle pour les Anglais est [rosbif](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rosbif#fr), Céline joue sur les mots en nous faisant passer à une présentation différente du morceau de bœuf.

Comment: Moi, je suis rosbif de chez rosbif. Si je dis cela, ça fait rire mes amis français.